# How to inspect errors in rable view files

Tags: debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rabl

I am using rabl with rails 3.2 application, I am getting errors in rabl view files but it's not pointing exact error line where error occured. So now I want debug view code for the line causes error, something like puts statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the instanciated variables in the same way you would with any other template.

haml

```
=puts @variable.inspect
```

erb

```
<%= puts @avariable.inspect %>
```

Comment: So one would think.  In rabl templates you can leave out the ruby escaping - just put a line with  puts "blah".